# Extract database from application sandbox

Tags: cocoa-touch, sqlite, sandbox

I'm making ios app, it will be supplied with the database which is copied to sandbox during the first launch. When it's copied it's being updated with further update anticipated. The problem is that I have to supply the applicaton with the updated database so that in the future it will bear lightweight updates.
So I need to find the application sandbox of the iPhone simulator and get this database to later put it into main bundle later on. How should I do that? I've tried different ways like sudo mv terminal commands moving from target path: /Users/xxxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/12EBDE40-0DC4-4A09-A8AF-2CEBCE5818B8/Documents/xxxxxx.sqlite еtc.
How should I do this properly? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is hot it's done programmatcally using:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
....
 [fileManager copyItemAtPath:targetPath toPath:@"/Users/xxxxx/ThisIsDBFile" error:&error];
```

And then you go to the directory and change the extension of the ThisIsDBFile to .sqlite or other